# Is the single responsibility principle directly related to class' dependencies?

Tags: c#, single-responsibility-principle

If a class is dependent through interfaces on more than one other class is that a violation of SRP, or is it only a violation if both interfaces are expected to change, or is this the wrong line of thought altogether?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The SRP is in principle entirely orthogonal to what and how many dependencies the class might have.

A class can have a single responsibility, but if that responsibility is complex to carry out it may have many dependencies on "sub-contractors" that take care of the menial work. In essence, your single responsibility is "coordinate these people so that X happens".

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense. If I thought of the principle meaning a class should only have one reason to change, does that not imply dependencies?

Comment: @Ford: No, "reason" means "a way in which you might want to change the behavior of this class". Dependencies are (or should be) interface types, so swapping out one implementation of `IDependency` for another is not a reason to change; in fact it might not result in even one line of code changing.

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily.  A class could still have one responsibility but have multiple dependencies.  Having multiple dependencies is often a *sign* that a class is doing to much, but it's not *proof* of that.

Answer (score 0):

If the class just call methods on those dependent interfaces, that wouldn't' be a violation of SRP since it's orchestrating a process calling different methods on different components, that would be the responsability.

It's hard to provide an exact answer without a specific context but in short: having dependencies with multiple interfaces it's not a violation of SRP per se.